# quote_char causing fits in ruby CSV import

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-2.0

I have a simple CSV file that uses the | (pipe) as a quote character. After upgrading my rails app from Ruby 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 I'm getting an "CSV::MalformedCSVError: Missing or stray quote in line 1" error.

If I pop open vim and replace the | with regular quotes, single quotes or even "=", the file works fine, but | and * result in the error. Anyone have any thoughts on what might be causing this? Here's a simple one-liner that can reproduce the error:

```
@csv = CSV.read("public/sample_file.csv", {quote_char: '|', headers: false})
```

Also reproduced this in Ruby 2.0 and also in irb w/out loading rails.

Edit: here are some sample lines from the CSV

```
|076N102                 |,|CARD                                    |,|         1|,|NEW|,|PCS       |
|07-1801                 |,|BASE                                    |,|        18|,|NEW|,|PCS       |
```

Comment: How about adding a few lines from public/sample_file.csv to show us the data?

Comment: @hd1 done - please see above!

Comment: That doesn't give me an exception. Are there any funny bytes in the file? If you `cat -v` the CSV, does anything look odd?

Comment: @muistooshort no weird characters. Here's a [link to the sample file](http://www.filedropper.com/samplestock) If you prefer, [here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/IG9shro.png) of the output of cat -v

Comment: CSV.foreach has the problem too. If you remove the quote_char option, everything works fine.

Comment: @Fred everything does not work fine. Add a single " in any field and you'll see why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've just discovered a bug in CSV ruby module.
From csv.rb :

```
1587:  @re_chars =   /#{%"[-][\\.^$?*+{}()|# \r\n\t\f\v]".encode(@encoding)}/
```

This Regexp is used to escape characters conflicting with special regular expression symbols, including your "pipe" char `|` .
I don't see any reason for the prepending `[-]`, so if you do remove it, your example starts to work:

**edit: the hyphen has to be escaped inside character set expression (surrounded with brackets `[]`) only when not as the leading character. So had to update the fixed Regexp:**

```
1587:  @re_chars =   /#{%"(?<!\\[)-(?=.*\\])|[\\.^$?*+{}()|# \r\n\t\f\v]".encode(@encoding)}/

CSV.read('sample.csv', {quote_char: '|'})
# [["076N102                 ",
#  "CARD                                    ",
#  "         1", "NEW", "PCS       "],
# ["07-1801                 ",  
#  "BASE                                    ",
#  "        18", "NEW", "PCS       "]]
```

**As most languages does not support lookbehind expressions with quantifiers, Ruby included, I had to write it as a negative version for the left bracket. It would also match hyphens with missing left one of a bracket pair. If you'd find a better solution, leave a comment pls.**

Glad to hear any comments before fill in a bug report to ruby-lang.org .

Comment: Ruby 2.0.0p195 was just released and it doesn't fix this issue, so filing a bug and submitting a patch would be much appreciated if you're up for it.

Comment: Somebody already did filled the bug report - https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8405